# What is the FPGA with the highest LEs / $?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga

Well, what is the FPGA with more Logic Elements per Dollar? I already tried to search some sites but the filters for the products do not include that option.

Comment: LEs are a rather nebulous metric as not all are the same. There’s not too many fpga vendors, so it should be reasonably easy to do a price comparison.

Comment: What volume? For pricing is a major factor.

Comment: Generally, look at the larger members of relatively recent budget FPGA families from the biggest manufacturers (e.g. Spartan-x family). This is too close to a purchasing recommendation question for a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been researched by UofT and Umass in the link below.

“ In between these extremes is a spectrum of logic block choices ranging from fine to coarse-grain logic blocks. FPGA architects over the last two decades have selected basic logic blocks made of transistors (noted above) [144], NAND gates [160], an interconnection of multiplexers [79], lookup tables [49], and PAL-style wide-input gates [217]. These choices were originally driven by intuitive insights on the part of architects, typically with very little data or analysis, with a few exceptions [79]. In this survey, we discuss how the research foundations for choosing a logic block were established, and then focus on the effect of logic block functionality on the three key metrics: **area, speed, and power. In this discussion, we use silicon area as the proxy for cost, as is common.** For a more detailed survey on the specifics of the logic blocks mentioned above, see [167] or [43].”

[https://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/~jayar/pubs/kuon/foundtrend08.pdf](https://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/%7Ejayar/pubs/kuon/foundtrend08.pdf)